# Как узнать какой тип данных у числа в строке?

Tags: java, swing

Делаю свой калькулятор возник вопрос в том, как узнать какой тип данных в строке у числа: double или int
Например если введу "12,3 / 3";

```
 String[] test = field.getText().split("\\s+");
```

Как сделать условия на проверку типа данных?
в массиве если брать элементы то выдает 12,3 все нормально.

Comment: Тип данных определяется переменной которой присваивается значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае достаточно проверить содержит число в себе точку или нет. Перед этим неплохо все запятые заменить на точки.

Comment: Не могу теперь понять какой переменной присваивать элемент если не известно какое будет число целое или с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Вам сначала нужно проанализировать все выражение и понять какой результат вы ожидаете. Если у вас например два целых числа и выражение `7/2` то все равно нужен тип `double`.

Comment: Просто это вроде как калькулятор и мы не можем предсказать что будем вводить, я инициализировал переменные так Double.ParseDouble(String.ValueOf()), всё работает но в любом ответе есть точка например 10.0